# Android Apache POI error when reading Microsoft Word document: org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException Cannot resolve type for handle

Tags: android, kotlin, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I am trying to use Apache POI in my Android application so that I can read Microsoft Word files. I am integrating the POIA library which enables Apache POI usage on Android (https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/poi-android). However, when I run my code and read in a Word file, I receive the following error:

> Exception: org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: Cannot
>   resolve type for handle _XY_Q=space|R=space

Below is my code (I am receiving error on the first line):

```
var document = XWPFDocument(uri?.let { contentResolver.openInputStream(it) });
var extractor = XWPFWordExtractor(document);
var documentText = extractor.text; // Retrieve the document's text
```

At runtime I have the following code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl")
System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl")
System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl")
```

Below is my gradle (project-level):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.60'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    ext {
        poiVersion = '3.17'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.4.93'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Below is my gradle (app-level):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.diffchecker"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    // For developers using the Android Support Library
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
    implementation ("com.github.SUPERCILEX.poi-android:poi:$poiVersion") {
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    }
}
```

Below is the full stack trace:

```
I/System.out: Exception: org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: Cannot resolve type for handle _XY_Q=space|R=space@http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sF1327CCA741569E70F9CA8C9AF9B44B2.cttext7f5btype) - code 13
```

**IMPORTANT: I am trying to read in the contents of a Word file the USER SELECTED, not a Word file from a hardcoded path.**

Please include **ALL** the relevant code in your answer, and your code **should work on Android API 22**.

Comment: I did something like this years ago. "a word document" can have a few different formats. So make sure you know which format you've saved the file as.

Comment: @Blundell I am trying into read in Microsoft Word files.

Comment: Yep https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Office_filename_extensions

Comment: @Blundell The app should read in .docx and .doc files... all of the other extensions do not need to be considered

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android

Comment: @AdamLee have you managed to find a solution for this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

owner of the lib here. `poi-android` has only been tested with Excel files and is tailored to work well with proguard to minimize binary size for an app I wrote.

If I had to guess, [this](https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/poi-android/blob/e1231c732f35a7f984c8c0903a7fee15291f7385/poi/build.gradle#L15-L25) is causing your issue. For a more generic version of POI, use https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android (which is what my lib is based off of). You'll have to include the JAR from the [releases section](https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/releases/latest) into your source tree and add this Gradle dependency: `implementation files('path/to/file.jar')`. However, as you'll notice, the lib is quite large (13MB+), hence the reasoning behind modifying POI to my use case. I would recommend forking one of the libs and tailoring it to your use case.

Comment: how can you modify the source after you fork so that you can open .docx files? just not excluding 'schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/attribute' doesn't make it work. Including the centic9 jar does fix the issue, but the jar is very big

Answer (score 1):

Did you add proper `packagingOptions` in `build.gradle` ?

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
```

Also enable `multiDexEnabled`